# Can I use anonymous mmap() as a reentrant version of malloc()?

Tags: signals, virtual-memory, system-calls, mmap, reentrancy

Although `mmap()` requires a syscall and it can only allocate whole pages, maybe it could be used as a workaround to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`) from signal handlers.

The `malloc()` isn't reentrant, which results that if a signal is coming while the control is in `malloc()` (or `free()`, or `realloc()`), and its handler tries to use these functions, the process will likely crash.

But the `mmap()` of the libc is only a wrapper around the kernel api call of the same name, and thus it can maybe considered reentrant. Of course the allocated memory pages should be later unmapped.

Could this work?

Comment: `mmap` isn't signal-safe according to POSIX or the Linux man pages.

Comment: @Mat [In the glibc](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/view/head:/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap64.c), and very likely in practically every unix libc, the mmap is only a wrapper around the `mmap()` syscall, and thus its around 3 lines of worthy code doesn't contain anything which wouldn't be reentrant. Well, maybe it wouldn't confrom signal(7), but considering the hard reality, that posix == {99% linux + 1% solaris}, and considering the current signal hell, and considering the clearly visible intention of a committee to make impossible the dynamic memory

Comment: And yet POSIX and the Linux docs don't list it as async-safe. Being a syscall doesn't magically grant re-entrancy.

Comment: @Mat allocation in signal handlers in the api standard, I think here is the point where the disappointment is enough to look for non-standard ways to solve standard problems.

Comment: You solve this problem by not allocating in signal handlers (i.e. preallocate).

Comment: @Mat Well, of course they don't say it, but what will happen is a process gets a signal while it is a noninterruptable syscall? Maybe it will be my next question, but I don't think it would cause crash in kernel space.

Comment: @Mat It can't be done if I need to handle any deepness of signalhandler reentrancy.

Comment: @Mat I think, if a signal is coming while the control is in `sys_mmap()`, it will be queued and executed after the syscall returns. This results the possibility of losing non-rt signals (if more than 1 is coming, the second will be lost, even if SA_NODEFER was set), but it is not the only case where it can happen.

Comment: Neither the original documentation from SunOS, nor POSIX list mmap() as async unsafe. If you use the flag `MAP_ANON` that was introduced in the mid-1990s, you will only  need a single syscall() to get anonymous memory. Be sure not to use `MAP_FIXED`as this could unmap existing memory to allow mapping of the new chunk.

Comment: @schily I think _maybe_ for the possibility of microkernel-based posix systems could have been decided, that no syscall will be reentrant. But my "most probable" idea is worser. Thank you the important infos! I won't MAP_FIXED, malloc() also won't. The allocated address after a memory allocation should be clearly an outgoing parameter.

Comment: @Mat Sorry for the reent-rant. :-)

Comment: Somewhere I've read, that also glibc uses anonymous `mmap()` on 64-bit architectures for _all_ memory allocations over page size.

Comment: My next idea is that I use an AF_UNIX SOCK_DGRAM socketpair[] as reentrant buffer. I sent the data into one of the sockets (reentrantly), and then get it back from the serialized handler.